# Split list into current and archive items

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a list of items with issue numbers

```
 ID        Issue 
 apple     1 
 orange    1 
 apple     2 
 apple     3 
 orange    2
```

I would like to create two lists, one with the "current" items which are the ones with the highest issue number, and a second list which is all the others MINUS the current ones (call it archive)

Hows the best way to do this given my list will have approximately 1000 entries (fairly small)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to find the highest "Issue" per "ID":

```
var maxList = yourList.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                      .Select(x => x.Where(y => y.Id == x.Max(z => z.Id)))
                      .SelectMany(x => x);

var theRest = yourList.Except(maxList);
```

This will return "Orange / 2" and "Apple / 3" in the first list, and the other three records in the second list.

Comment: Thanks Grant, that's perfect

Answer (score 4):

This might help

```
var currentIssue = list.Max(x => x.Issue); 
var currentItems = list.Where(x => x.Issue == currentIssue).ToList();
var archiveItems = list.Where(x => x.Issue != currentIssue).ToList();
```

Comment: Rather than posting almost the same I took the freedom to edit your answer to improve the variable names :-)

Comment: @chiccodoro thanks.I didn't think variable names too much :))

Comment: Where do I pull maxNumber from? Do i need a ForEach loop or something?

Comment: @GordonCopestake don't you have a list?

Comment: Only the datatable I have shown (with a list of issues). There is no second list showing which is the max issue, if there was I wouldn't have a problem!

Comment: `list.Max(x => x.Issue)` returns maximum issue number! you don't need second list.First try the solution then complain about it!

Comment: I'm still not getting where the variable maxNumber is coming from. Sorry, probably being stupid

Comment: @GordonCopestake Max is an extension method.See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534962(v=vs.110).aspx) `Returns the maximum value in a sequence of values.`

Comment: I understand the .max bit, it's the maxNumber bit i'm not getting from this part: x => x.Issue == maxNumber, I dont know where maxNumber is coming from

Comment: I've finally clicked as to where it's come from by looking at the edit. The maxNumber is currentIssue! The variable changed name between line 1 and 2 of your answer!

Comment: @GordonCopestake ah,sorry you right. `chiccodoro` edited my answer and changed the variable names. but he forgot changing the query.

Comment: @Gordon: I am very sorry for the confusion I caused! The intent was to make it clearer to you... This should earn me the first "Obfuscation" badge for "making an answer completely invalid by making changes that appear to be helpful"

Comment: No problem, got there in the end! Thanks for your help all